# strapi not returning image url as attribute

Tags: javascript, axios, svelte, strapi

I'm trying to built a small picture gallery with svelte and strapi v4 for learning purposes.
I have my content type configured as shown in picture 1 ([Picture 1, content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M9t2.png)) and this is the code I use to make the get request to my strapi backend:

```
onMount(async () => {
try {
    const response = await instance.get("/api/picture-blog-posts")
    console.log(response);
    
} catch (e) {
    error = e
}
```

})
I added a few pictures through the Strapi Admin Panel and published them.
I was thinking, that I would get the image url as an attribute, but I don't:
[The data response I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzRYi.png)
I am not sure what I am supposed to different or where my problem is, because the response has all the data except the image data :/ 
So help will be very much appreciated.
Also I will gladly add more details, if you think they are needed. Just trying to keep it concise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To improve performance, Strapi V4 doesn’t return media files or relation data by default. Thus, you will need to adapt your request as it is outlined in the docs:

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest-api.html#fields-selection

Example with using `axios` and `qs`:

```js
  const query = qs.stringify({ 
      populate: '*',
      fields: '*',
      publicationState: 'live',
      locale: ['en','de'],
    }, {
      encodeValuesOnly: true, // prettify url
    });
    

    const url =`${REPLACEWITHYOURBASEURL}/api/settings-header?${query}`;   
    
    const result = await axios.get(url);
```

Comment: Another option to quickly retrieve the data is to append `?populate=*` to the query, e.g.: `http://strapi-url/api/items?populate=*`.